# Chat using Parse in android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, chat

I am developing chat application using parse. These will be a **group chat** application.

There are **many number of groups possible**. I have implemented parse and also have knowledge about it.

But I want to make it **real time chat application**.

**I know I can do it with the help of push notification but having lack knowledge of implementation.**

Can you guys please suggest me some other way of doing real time chat or how to exactly work with push notification to make real time chat application.

So here are some queries:

1. Can I develop group chat using parse ?
2. Does it feasible solution to use parse for real time chat ?
3. If yes , then how can i make it real time chat. ?

Comment: @Andrea : Thanks for edit.:-)

Answer (score 1):

Parse platform is not suitable for real-time chat applications as it does not support persistent websocket connections. You can still use Parse to send notifications but you should use other providers with real-time support like PubNub or Firebase

Comment: my whole databse will be on parse and chat will get start on basis of stored dara over there. So if i used PubNub or Firebase then how will i connect parse with it?

Comment: You will use Parse to store everything. PubNub provides the real-time message delivery system. You simply save all the messages,docs,images being sent to users on Parse database. For real-time message delivery to a user's device, you use PubNub API. See: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-collaboration-sync-parse-api-pubnub/

Comment: Okay..Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it and let you know for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Mo Nazemi's answer, you should also look into [Layer](https://layer.com/) and [SINCH](https://www.sinch.com/), sinch alos includes VoIP

Comment: I have already used sinch with parse and it is good for one to one chat but not group chat.